# SQLLoader without ControlFile

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Is there any way I can run SQLLoader and put in the command line all the options I would normally write in the control file?
The reason I ask is, I need to load different .csv in different tables at different times, and It would be much easier if I hadn't to create a controlfile each time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the Control File name for running the SQL Loader.
To load the data for multiple .csv files, you can, create multiple Control Files, one for each csv files and run them as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

If on *nix you can avoid having to make an actual file by using a named pipe, but be sure you either redirect log/bad to /dev/null or specify their location explicitly so that the utility doesn't crash when trying to write into /dev/fd on a .bad or .log auto generated file name that doesn't exist.

```
sqlldr <args> bad=/path/to/writeable/bad.log log=/path/to/writeable/log.log control=<(echo "load data infile .......")
```

Just make sure to escape inside your echo statement so that it's output mirrors exactly what would be inside control file, if it was an actual file.